# Reflection and Outlook AppointmentItem GetProperties

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following question:

Why do I get nothing when I do appointment.GetType().GetProperties() but at the same time .GetMembers, .GetMethods work.

appointment refers to an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem

I need to dynamically build a list of properties on a given AppointmentItem object. I am able to set the properties them once I have a name, but I also want to do the reverse, to get all the names and iterate through the names to get the values for storage.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using reflection, you can try using [ItemsProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171454%28v=office.11%29.aspx).  It's available in all the MailItem objects

Comment: Thanks! Wished I had thought of that earlier.... thanks. that should work as well...